# TexLive: anybody know of a good step by step guide for dummies?

Tags: texlive, linux, linuxfedora

I am trying to get TeX Live 2016 up and running, but keep facing one hurdle after another.

I have followed different guides, and the answers to various questions, tried the net install and the iso install, on Fedora and Debian, but it doesn't seem to help, I am also rather new to Linux.

My latest issue is that sudo cannot find the bash commands `mktexslr` or `tlmgr`.

I have added the path as mentioned on the texlive quickinstall, I edited the visudo file, as mentioned by a user on this site, nothing works.

So my question, here, is if someone is aware of a dummy proof step by step guide to a working installion of TeX Live that also covers Linux admin issues?

Any tips most appreciated!!!

[Edit: so I think i have found the dummy way to get this to work: cd to the folder containing the binaries (bin folder in TexLive folder), and then sudo and drag and drop the binaries in the termainal, good enough for now ... I guess the linking part is above my pay grade for now]

Comment: I've installed TL via net - install so many times on my Linux machines (Fedora/OpenSuSE) (due to updates, not due to problems) etc. and never run into problems, it works out of the box, so it is quite unclear what goes wrong in your case

Comment: if you are a new user and have debian why do you need to install texlive at all? if you need a bleeding edge installation it's a good idea to get the upstream texlive direct but for the vast majority of users just using the texlive that's in debian is fine.

Comment: Hi, and Thanks for your answers! I was using the version from Debian, but i was having issues, and read somewhere that it is better to get the new version, and hoped that might help. @Christian Hupfer: I am new to both Linux and TexLive, and have just got Miktex running properly on windows with some extra packages and fonts, also with trial and error. My main issue now is that the bash commands are not found, but as this seems to have been asked and answered in other posts here, i was hoping for a dummy version to sort out such issues :-)

Comment: The commands are not found if the environment has not been set up correct. You have to add the TeX Live binary directory in front of PATH.

Comment: @Schweinebacke This seems to be the issue. I have entered this in the terminal: PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH, but it didn't solve it, i also edited visudo and added the same path to it under default, also didn't help. Is there a dummy friendly version of your explanation ? Or did i do something wrong ?

Comment: Since you usually wouldn't need to run LaTeX with administrative privileges, you may find it easiest to just say `sudo $(which tlmgr) update --all` (or whatever), which will substitute the explicit path.